# 7 Seas or The Great Ocean?

Tags: halacha, blessing, natural-phenomenon

Seeing the ocean warrants the recital of a blessing. (Assume for this question like the opinions that the proper bracha is שעשה את הים הגדול as opposed to עושה מעשה בראשית.) It is only recited if one has not seen the ocean in 30 days. (Shulchan Aruch OC [224:13](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=276) and [228:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=282) and Mishna Berura there)

Do the Pacific and Atlantic Oceans count as separate for the purposes of the 30 day break between sightings necessary to warrant a new blessing?

Comment: You were [warned](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/755/weekly-topic-challenge-5772-18-week-of-mishpatim-5772-unusual-blessings#comment1634_755) this was coming!

Comment: **Congratulations! This question won the [weekly topic challenge](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/441) for _Mishpatim_ 5772!**

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52318&st=&pgnum=279

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shu"t Bitzel Hahochma (R' Betzalel Stern) deals with a similar issue In Vol. 2 Siman 14. He discusses whether one should make a second beracha on the Mediterranean if he made one (within 30 days) on the ocean. He concludes that since they require the same beracha (according to him) and they are connected, a second beracha is not recited.

> לפימש"כ לעיל (סי' י"ב אות ד' ה' י"ד) דהעיקר לברך בין על ראיית ים
>   התיכון ובין על ראיית האוקינוס, שעשה את הים הגדול כדעת הכנה"ג ולהקת
>   פוסקים העומדים בשיטתו ולזה הסכים גם הגאון הראבד"ק דעיה"ק ירושלים ת"ו
>   (עיי' סי' י"ג), *נראה פשוט דכיון דברכת שניהם שוה, בברכת שעשה את היה"ג,
>   שבירך על ים התיכון פטר גם ברכת ים אוקינוס.*   ואף שהוא נוסע כמה ימים
>   בים התיכון לפני שמגיע לאוקינוס ונמצא הפסק רב והיסח הדעת בין הברכה
>   לראית האוקינוס, לענ"ד ז"א דלדידהו כיון שברכת שניהם שוה והם מחוברים יחד
>   נחשבים כים אחד (עיי' סי' י"ב אות ו'), וממילא כיון שראה קצהו האחד ובירך
>   עליו, כבר נפטר כל ל' יום מלברך עוד על ראייתו ואפי' כשהוא רואה אח"כ
>   קצהו האחר של הים, ואפילו אם הי' בינתיים ביבשה, כל שהוא תוך ל' יום
>   מראית הים בפעם האחרונה הרי הוא פטור מלברך עוד, ולכן גם כאשר יגיע
>   לאוקינוס א"צ לברך.‏

I would assume that similarly here, since the Atlantic and Pacific share a beracha (according to everyone) and are connected, he would rule that one would not recite a second beracha.